# Titanium : Attach objects/variables with a view

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am creating some views in a loop iterating over list of objects. Now I want to register event with each view, which does something on the current object of the list.

```
for (var vs = 1; vs < 4; vs++) {
    iMovie = moviesList[vs];
    if (!iMovie) {
        break;
    }

    var loopView = Ti.UI.createView({
        ....
    });

    loopView.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var mv = iMovie;
        Ti.API.info("Movie: " + mv);
        if (mv) {
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

This code is not working, the log which is printed is : `Movie: undefined`.

So my question is how I can use the loop variable in the event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
var loopView - [];
var iMovie;
for (var vs = 1; vs < 4; vs++) {
    iMovie = moviesList[vs];
    if (!iMovie) {
        break;
    }

    loopView[vs] = Ti.UI.createView({
        _iMovie : iMovie
    });

    loopView[vs].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var mv = e.source._iMovie;
        Ti.API.info("Movie: " + mv);
        if (mv) {
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I'll start that what you are doing in the code above could potentially cause a memory leak since you are holding a reference to the iMovie variable.

what you should try doing is:

```
var mv = e.source;
```

this will return the source object that fired the click event.